# Passing item data to activity

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve the data from my database and send it to each Recyclerview item, so far I've retrieved the data and populated my recyclerviewer however, I am not sure how to send this data to the page of each item. I have created an onclick that returns the position of the item, and I can get the position of the item inside the profile activity with an

```
putExtra()
```

but not sure how to do the same for the Names and images of the items.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<Buildings> mUploads;

private String name;


private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
private ValueEventListener mDBListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Buildings");

    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, mUploads);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

    mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mUploads.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Buildings upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Buildings.class);
                upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                mUploads.add(upload);

                name = upload.getName();
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

         //   mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, mUploads);

        //    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {


   // String buildingName = mUploads.get(position).toString();

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity2.class);
   // mainIntent.putExtra("pos", buildingName);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onWhatEverClick(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Whatever click at position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
    Buildings selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
    final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();

    StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImage_url());
    imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mDatabaseRef.removeEventListener(mDBListener);
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.Java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Buildings> mUploads;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Buildings> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}

@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.buildings_row_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Buildings uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    Glide.with(mContext).load(mUploads.get(position).getImage_url()).into(holder.imageView);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
        View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;
    LinearLayout view_container;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.building_name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case 1:
                        mListener.onWhatEverClick(position);
                        return true;
                    case 2:
                        mListener.onDeleteClick(position);
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                mListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
        MenuItem doWhatever = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Do whatever");
        MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");

        doWhatever.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);

    void onWhatEverClick(int position);

    void onDeleteClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

}
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Did you meant to send whole Buildings.class in your intent?

Answer (score 1):

First make your model class Buildings `Serializable`, then in `onItemClick()` get item value and pass this data to next activity to get all data related to this item.

```
Buildings currentItem = mUploads.get(position);
mainIntent.putExtra("buildingData", buildingName);
```

in detail activity class get item data:

```
Buildings data = (Buildings) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("buildingData");
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you not using Interface for this...
Create an Interface

```
public interface SendData {
public void mainData(int Pos, BeanData data); // this is your complete bean class which is send from adapter's item click to main class
```

}

Make object of this interface in your adatper :-

```
SendData sendData;
```

then under constructore :- `this.sendData = sendData;`

then onitemClick :-

```
sendData.mainData(position, data); // herer data is your bean class
```

and then implement this interface in your  Mainactivity
that's it....

Make sure you already send Interface object from MainAcitvity to recyclerview when setting your adapter with recycler view data.